# Do online University Systems close during holidays and are unable to process submitted information?

Tags: phd, thesis, university

My examiner has recently told me that he is unable to submit information to the Uni system about the result of his examination of my revised thesis.
I am uncertain of the name of the online system used by my university but I assume it is an off the shelf standardized system that is likely used by many other institutions(How can I find out what system is used?).

> Do online University Systems really close during holidays and are unable to
> process submitted grading information?

Comment: What did he say *why* is is "unable to submit information"? That would be the right question.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth he said something along the lines that he is unable to input the information on the system likely due to the system being unable to process the information during the holidays. I am a bit suspicious of that so I was wondering if anyone from here is encountered anything similar to this before.

Comment: The only person who can definitely answer the question is your prof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that systems will shut down during holidays. Email servers run as usual. Payroll systems, etc. keep on keeping on. But when decisions are made they are most likely made by humans, many of whom will be away from their desks and workstations.

Your [earlier question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/205194/75368) seems to indicate a situation in which human actions are needed.

To know which systems are used, and you might not be told, contact the IT (Information Technology) organization at the university and ask. But, the answer would probably come from a human, who is probably enjoying a break at the moment.

Your frustration is understandable, but the people downstream from you who want information about your degree will also understand the limitations of the system and are unlikely (IMO) to punish you for things you can't control. Their own systems will have similar limitations.

Note, as I've done in a comment elsewhere, that many, probably most, university systems have people available to answer phones and handle departmental emails for most of the holiday season, other than the holidays themselves. It will likely be reduced staff. And emails will still go through, though recipients may not be reading it, nor answering it. Academic holidays are for academics, not necessarily for academic staff. Things important to the running of the university still get done, but that doesn't imply dealing immediately with academic issues. You might be able to reach the department office (a staff person, perhaps) by phone during holiday seasons and ask what help might be available to resolve the issue.

My best guess is that you will be fine in spite of the frustrations. If the system were driven by completely automated AI systems I'd think you would be less pleased in general with the results as those systems make many (many) errors. Artificial Intelligence is certainly artificial, but not so much intelligent in spite of the name (hype).

Answer (score 1):

My own experience is that any maintenance required for these systems is done between semesters.  Sometimes the systems remain available, sometimes they are taken down.  When taken down, it's never for more than a few hours.

That said, "unable to submit" can mean many things.  The system used for managing grad committees at my school are separate from the main LMS, and I've had trouble logging into it myself.

Comment: Are you sure about "never"? Larger changes, like migration to a new system, could take days.

Comment: Planned vs actual times tend to diverge quite strongly…